# Treverse list of tuples to compare and report min, max

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My previous question was not understood, so I rephrase and post this one.
I have a list of tuple for `(class, n_class_examples)` like this:

```py
my_list = (0, 126), (1, 192), (2, 330), (3, 952) ]
```

So I am interested in generating a function, that takes in such a list, compare each tuple against all others, and in each case reports which class has smaller number of samples (`min_class`), and which has the larger number of samples (`max_class`).

```py
def get_min_max_class(current_list):
    for tn, tn+1: # tn -> 1-tuple, tn+1 any other tuple not tn
        if tn[1] < tn+1[1]
            smaller_class = tn[0]
            larger_class = tn+1[0]
        smaller_class = tn+1[0]
        larger_class = tn[0]
    return # smaller, larger of the 2 compared in each case
```

So that:

```py
get_min_max_class(my_list)
# would perform the comparison like so:
(0, 126) v (1, 192) -> min_class = 0, max_class = 1 # in this case
(0, 126) v (2, 330) -> min_class = 0, max_class = 2 # and in this case
(0, 126) v (3, 952) -> min_class = 0, max_class = 3 # and here ..
(1, 192) v (2, 330) -> min_class = 1, max_class = 2 # ...
(1, 192) v (3, 952) -> min_class = 1, max_class = 3
(2, 330) v (3, 952) -> min_class = 2, max_class = 3
```

Forgive my definition of function, but I want the function to iteratively compare those items, each time, report which is larger and which is smaller.

Comment: By "class", do you mean "the first value in the tuple"?

Comment: yes, it designates the class label.

Comment: It not clear why you are not using the built in `min()` and `max()` functions. Also, you example would be more useful if it showed which part of the tuple you are trying to compare. The results are the same if you are comparing the first elements or the second.

Comment: @Mark I am not sure how to iteratively pick each pair of the list elements (tuple), only then I would can use `min()`, `max()`.

Comment: But your function `get_min_max_class()` just returns a single value. It’s not clear what “iteratively pick” means here.

Comment: @Mark that's why I added "Forgive my definition of function..." that's just a skeletal definition, anyway I changed it.

Comment: @Mark As illustrated at the end of the question, suppose it takes `my_list`, the function compares each 2, to report min, max.

Comment: I still have no idea what you are asking for.  Please give an actual example of what you want the function to return, given the `my_list` input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the list of pairs generated by `itertools.combintions`, the process each pair individually using `min` and `max`.

```
from itertools import combinations
from operator import itemgetter

first = itemgetter(0)
second = itemgetter(1)

def get_min_max_class(current_list):
    for pair in combinations(current_list, 2):
        p0, p1 = pair
        min_class = first(min(pair, key=second))
        max_class = first(max(pair, key=second))
        print(f'{p0} v {p1} -> min_class = {min_class}, max_class = {max_class}')

get_min_max_class(my_list)
```

If you want to return a list of results, rather than simply printing a report, you'll have to define what exactly you want to return.

Comment: You can simplify `min_class` and `max_class` together using `sorted` instead of `min` + `max`: there are only two items in a pair. (and you need to fix a couple of typos in f-string, probably using `f'...{min_class=}` - have you renamed `smaller` to `min_class`?) Great functional solution!

Answer (score 0):

Python's sorted(), min(), and max() functions take as second argument a 'key' that let's you specify how to calculate the sorting for different objects, using lambda functions. In this case, you want to sort the tuples based on the value of the second element and return the corresponding first value.

So, if I wanted the 'max' in your case I would do:

```
max_class = max(my_list, key=lambda x: x[1])[-1]
```

The lambda expression, if it's new to you, is saying "sort the item x in the list based on whatever you find at x[1]". Then, take the final element of the sorted list to get the class with the most samples, or whatever it was exactly.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Well, I am not simply sort to get min,max. I want iteratively pick each one, compare it with all others, and i every comparison determine the smalller and the larger of the two compared.

Comment: Why? What does that achieve that using min/max would not?

Comment: From above I can see that you want to generate pairs of items from the list. Check out itertools.combinations(): https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations you want to pass as argument your list and the number 2.

Comment: But I still don't understand why you want to do this in the way you have specified...